# Android MediaPlayer unknown error

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

I am creating a MediaPlayer instance in MainActivity's onCreate() method like this

```
 MediaPlayer mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, Uri.fromFile(new File("/storage/emulated/0/soundrecorder/My recording #26.wav")));
```

It is created successfully but I get this error:

```
07-06 18:33:44.266 18366-18366/com.audiorecorder.wel.voicerecorder E/MediaPlayer-JNI: JNIMediaPlayerFactory: bIsQCMediaPlayerPresent 0
07-06 18:33:44.267 18366-18366/com.audiorecorder.wel.voicerecorder E/MediaPlayer-JNI: JNIMediaPlayerFactory: bIsQCMediaPlayerPresent 0
```

Also tried this but the same error on logcat:

```
MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
    try {
        mp.setDataSource(this, Uri.fromFile(new File("/storage/emulated/0/soundrecorder/My recording #26.wav")));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    mp.prepareAsync();
    mp.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            mp.start();
        }
    });
```

I have tried different audio files with different formats but result is the same error. I have also tried searching the answer on stackoverflow but could not resolve the issue. Can you help me on this?

Comment: are you running it on device or emulator?

Comment: Running it on Motorola Moto G running Nougat 7.1.1

Comment: one problem that I see is the spaces in your song file name, try removing them. It might work out.

Comment: I tried it but the problem is still there.

Comment: try another audio file, also with another format like `mp3`

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is some issue with your file. Update that with this :

musicUri = android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;

And then follow these steps:

```
    1.  getLoaderManager().initLoader(0,null,this);
    2.  @Override
        public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
            switch (id){
                case 0 : return new CursorLoader(getApplicationContext(),musicUri,null,null,null,null);        
            return new Loader<>(this);
        }

3. @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
        switch (loader.getId()) {
            case 0 :
                if(data != null && data.moveToFirst()) {
                    songTitleColumnIndex = data.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE);
                    do {
                        songTitle = data.getString(songTitleColumnIndex);
                        songsList.add(songTitle);
                    } while (data.moveToNext());
                }
                break;
```

So the SongTitles are being put in the SongList which is an ArraList of String Type.

Hope This Helps.

Comment: why put song titles in an array list?

Comment: I am just maintaining an ArrayList of SongTitles, which I would be showing as the list of songs present in my device.

Comment: It should. You try and revert back.

Comment: This does not solve my probelm which occurs when creating a new MediaPlayer instance. Loading a list of song titles from database is not what is asked in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a FileInputStream to start your MediaPlayer with a FileDescriptor instead:

```
String yourFilePath = "/wherever/your/file/is.wav";

MediaPlayer mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

try{
    FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(yourFilePath);
    mPlayer.setDataSource(inputStream.getFD());
    inputStream.close();

    mPlayer.prepare();
    mPlayer.start();

}catch (IOException e){
    Log.e("IOException", e.getMessage());
}
```